# how to make a p text fill a div in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have the following `<p>` with class description and I want it to fill the remaining empty space of its container div (`summary-container`):

```
<div class="summary-container">
  <h2>Title here</h2>

  <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conoasnasdnaonaosnasodnoasd ad
    dnandoanoadn oandoasnoasdn osandoand ods asnadnsoasdndsanasdn
    dnandoanoadn oandoasnoasdn osandoand ods asnadnsoasdndsanasdn
    dnandoanoadn oandoasnoasdn osandoand ods asnadnsoasdndsanasdn
    dnandoanoadn oandoasnoasdn osandoand ods asnadnsoasdndsanasdn
  </p>
</div>
```

this are my styles:

```
#what-to-do .summary-container {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


#what-to-do .description {
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

But this is how it looks:

[image]

I want it to fill the part as the black lines show
[In this demo of ionic it works just how I want it to work.](http://play.ionic.io/app/8ed5f0942272)

So weird!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well I just checked with chrome debugger and that div is inside an ionic list item which it's giving it some properties so I changed this and now its working:

```
#what-to-do .description {
  white-space: normal;
}
```